# Is it relevant to standardize data before PCA on MNIST digits dataset?

Tags: python, data-science

Since the features for the MNIST digits dataset (the pixels) are all expressed in the same units and are comprised between [0:255], is it relevant to standardize them (apply StandardScaler from scikitlearn) or a simple normalization would be sufficient (like minmaxscaler)?